# Combining phpdoc with existing docbook

Tags: phpdoc, docbook

I'd like to include some phpdoc-generated documentation into my already existing docbook documentation.

My idea was to let phpdoc generate the documentation in the docbook-format and then import parts (based on packages and subpackages) of it using XInclude. I'm using Docbook 5 for my documentation. Is there any way to achieve this?

---

What I tried this far is generating a docbook using `XML:DocBook/peardoc2:default` as phpdoc parameter.

PHPDocumentor's docbook is divided into several files - thats great, but the files look something like this

```
<chapter id="package.default">
<title>default</title>
&package.default.default;
&package.default.foobar;
</chapter>
```

As far as I understand those are external entities, but they need to be referenced in a DTD - making them useless for my effort, as there is no DTD generated by phpdoc and I don't want to include a file for every class and method by hand.

Answer (score 0):

First, if this is really supposed to be docbook 5, you need "xml" before "id" like this:

```
<chapter xml:id="package.default">
```

Second, you could use an XML Catalog to hold all your entity references: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Catalogs.html